# Apply JSLink client side rendering to Content Query Web Part

Tags: content-query-web-part, client-side-rendering

We are using SP2013 on-premise standard edition (hence content search web part is not supported). I have applied custom rending by inserting a JSLink to some list view. Later I need to apply the same custom rendering to a Content Query Web Part. However no JSLink properties is available for CQWP. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client Side Rendering can only be done on LVWP (List View WebParts)

The CQWP (Content Query WebPart) is styled with XSLT: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xslt-list-view-web-part